# Managed metadata field values red on restored site

Tags: managed-metadata, migration

I know this question has been asked and answered numerous times already, but I am still running into a problem. I used Backup-SPSite and Restore-SPSite to migrate a site from one SP 2010 farm to another. The site contains a managed metadata column, and the managed metadata DB from the source server was backed up and restored on the target.

Now when I edit the metadata of one of the items that contains the managed metadata column, the terms are all red. If I click in the managed metadata field and then click back out again, the items all turn black. The trouble is, I don't want to have to do this for every item, and I also don't want the Modified Date to change for every item.

I did find this script, which is supposed to solve exactly this problem:
http://mymemorysucks.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/invalid-terms-in-managed-metadata-field/

Despite the fact that several people report this script working for them in the comments, when I run it I get an exception on the call to $item.Update(). The exception states:

> Exception calling "Update" with "1" argument(s): "The URL
>   'Lists/XXX/YYY.doc" is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or
>   folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current
>   Web.

The file is definitely there, and the account running the script does have permissions to edit it. Also, all documents are checked in, and check-out is NOT required to edit a document. What could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. I was able to use the script mentioned in the original post, but needed to modify it slightly. That script was setting the new value of the managed metadata field to $existingTerms[0].GetPath(). I needed to modify that value to remove everything before the last semi-colon ";" character.

In other words, replace:

```
$existingTerms[0].GetPath()
```

With:

```
$eistingTerms[0].GetPath().Substring($existingTerms[0].GetPath().LastIndexOf(";") + 1)
```

After doing that, the call to $item.Update() worked and my items were all successfully updated.